# Java HashMap Duplicate bucket entries

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a question about HashMaps. We are writing a small-c(-ish) compiler and for that we are using a symbol table. We are implementing this using a hashmap.

Now to take scopes into account we use a stack. So everytime we enter a new scope we push a token that signifies this on the stack. We then put all the keys from the hashmap on the stack for all the symbols we encounter. So far so good.

When we exit scope, we pop the stack until we reach the token. Every symbol we pass before this we have to take out of our hashmap.

Given following piece of code:

```
{ 
    a = 5;
    {
        a = 5;
    }
}
```

Will the hashmap accept this? As in, I would enter them using a as a key. That won't be a problem, but when popping and having to remove these, will Java be able to make a difference between the two objects? Or will the second one just overwrite the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map javadoc

> An object that maps keys to values. A map **cannot contain duplicate
>   keys**; each key can map to at most one value.

Answer (score 3):

I think using trees it's better solution. Each node of tree define block of visibility for variable. In case of nested blocks, leaf node will override value of variable.

Comment: Hmm, we will discuss this possibility.

Answer (score 1):

No, this won't work, because you may only have one value for a given key in a map.

I would use a delegation mechanism between scopes. When you enter a new scope, create a new Scope object, and store every new symbol defined in this scope inside a map contained by the SCope object. Make the Scope object point to its enclosing Scope (and thus delegating to this enclosing Scope to find the value of variables which are not in the map), and then make the created SCope the current one. Once you exit from the block, simply take the enclosing scope of the ended scope and make that the current scope.

Answer (score 1):

I want to suggest you 2 solutions.

1. User maps of maps. This is how JNDI works. Each namespace may contain variables themselves and subcontext that is map itself and may contain variables of its level.
2. Use dot notation for keys. Something like 1.a for the first variable a defined in outer context and 1.1.a for the second one.